# How does the statements inside this IF statement work?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc

I just recently started my programming education within Inter-process commmunications and this piece of code was written within the parent processs code section. From what I have read about `write()`, it returns `-1` if it failed, `0` if nothing was written to the `pipe()` and a positive integer if successful. How exactly does `sizeof(value)` help us identify this? Isn't `if(write(request[WRITE],&value,sizeof(value) < 1)` a much more reading friendlier alternative to what the `sizeof(value)`.

```
if(sizeof(value)!=write(request[WRITE],&value,sizeof(value)))
{
     perror("Cannot write thru pipe.\n");
     return 1;
}
```

Code clarification: The variable `value` is an input of a digit in the parent process which the parent then sends to the child process through a pipe the child to do some arithmic operation on it.

Any help of clarification on the subject is very much apprecaited.

Edit: How do I highlight my system functions here when asking questions?

Comment: Re edit: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for markdown instructions.

Answer (score 5):

This also captures a successful but *partial* write, which the application wants to consider being a failure.

It's slightly easier to read without the pointless parnethesis:

```
if(write(request[WRITE], &value, sizeof value) != sizeof value)
```

So, for instance, if `value` is an `int`, it might occupy 4 bytes, but if the `write()` just writes 2 of those it will return `2` which is captured by this test.

At least in my opinion. Remember that `sizeof` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a `read`, that's a `write`.  The principle is almost the same, but there's a bit of a twist.

As a general rule you are correct: `write()` could return a "short count", indicating a partial write.  For instance, you might ask to write 2000 bytes to some file descriptor, and `write` might return a value like 1024 instead, indicating that 976 (2000 - 1024) bytes were *not* written but no actual error occurred.  (This occurs, for instance, when receiving a signal while writing on a "slow" device like a tty or pty.  Of course, the application must decide what to do about the partial write: should it consider this an error?  Should it retry the remaining bytes?  It's pretty common to wrap the `write` in a loop, that retries remaining bytes in case of short counts; the stdio `fwrite` code does this, for instance.)

With pipes, however, there's a special case: [writes of sufficiently small size (less than or equal to `PIPE_BUF`) are atomic](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html).  So *assuming* `sizeof(value) <= PIPE_BUF`, and that this really is writing on a pipe, this code is correct: `write` will return either `sizeof(value)` or `-1`.

(If `sizeof(value)` is 1, the code is correct—albeit misleading—for any descriptor: write never returns zero.  The only possible return values are `-1` and some positive value between 1 and the number of bytes requested-to-write, inclusive.  This is where `read` and `write` are not symmetric with respect to return values: `read` can, and does, return zero.)